# Implode with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, implode

this toI can't get this to work :

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){ 
$go = $result->getVisitors();  
} 
echo $output = implode(',', $go);
```

or this :

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){ 
$go = $result->getVisitors();  
echo $output = implode(',', $go);
}
```

I get this error always : Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$go` and paste the output here.

Comment: Crush, could you please explain yourself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong

```
echo $output = implode(',', $go);
```

This will echo the outcome of the assignment of the `=`

You should try

```
echo implode(',', $go);
```

Or this

```
$output = implode(',', $go);
echo $output;
```

Or

```
var_dump($go);
```

**Edit**

```
$array = array();
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){ 
    $array[] = $result->getVisitors();  
} 
echo implode($array, ",");
```

Comment: Not working :/ It tried : foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){ $go = $result->getVisitors();echo implode(',', $go);  }

Comment: what does `var_dump($go)` give you?

Comment: That means that `$go` is a one, the integer 1, not an array so `implode` will fail. Its not an array. What framework are you using? What should `getVisitors()` return?

Comment: It should return a list of visit (per hour) like : 14897864. Which should be 1,5,89,65,47,78      To be more clear, I'm using GAPI from Google analytics, and this numbers are number of visits.

Comment: What about `var_dump($result);` inside the foreach.

Comment: So, is there a way to remove the comma for the last foreach ?

Comment: I got this : object(gapiReportEntry)[27]
  private 'metrics' => 
    array
      'visitors' => int 0
  private 'dimensions' => 
    array
      'hour' => string '00' (length=2)
object(gapiReportEntry)[29]
  private 'metrics' => 
    array
      'visitors' => int 1
  private 'dimensions' => 
    array
      'hour' => string '01' (length=2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46705/discussion-between-jake-n-and-user1708580)

Comment: For the previous comment, I just put two results. But When I put var_dump($go) in the foreach, I get : int 0
int 1
int 3
int 0
int 2
int 0
int 0
int 0
int 0
int 2
int 0
int 0
int 3
int 1
int 1
int 3
int 1
int 3
int 0
int 1
int 1
int 0
int 1
int 1